# Instantiate class inside a Constructor (c++)

Tags: c++, oop, c++17

Is the use of new/delete appropriate here? Or any way to avoid them?

The point: class myOptions need an instance of Submarine. The Parameter are known at the time the myOptions-Construcor is called.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Submarine
{
public:
    Submarine(std::string o)
    {
        std::cout << "create class Submarine: " << o << "\n";
    }
    ~Submarine(){};
};

class myOptions
{
public:
    myOptions(std::string o):option(o)
    {
        std::cout << "create class myOption: " << option << "\n";
        submarine = new Submarine(option);
    }
    ~myOptions()
    {
        delete submarine;
    }
private:
    std::string option{};
    Submarine *submarine;
};

int main(void){
    myOptions{"help"};
}
```

Comment: For your example as shown, it is not necessary that `myOptions` contain a `Submarine *`.   A `Submarine` will suffice.    It is usually better to initialise members of a class (whether pointers or not) in the constructor initialiser list, not in the body of constructors.    There are cases (e.g. `Submarine` is a polymorphic base) where a pointer is needed - but a smart pointer (like `std::unique_ptr<Submarine>`) is preferable to a raw pointer (`Submarine *`) .

Comment: *"Is the use of new/delete appropriate here?"* I would say that only valid case is when you implement your own smart pointers/allocators/containers. Else use existing smart pointer/containers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use dynamic memory here:

```
class myOptions
{
public:
    myOptions(std::string o):option(o), submarine(o)
    {
        std::cout << "create class myOption: " << option << "\n";
    }

private:
    std::string option{};
    Submarine submarine;
};
```

If you really need to use dynamic memory allocation (and you are not allowed to use smart pointers), you must apply [the rule of five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) to your class. Currently it will blow up your program anytime you decide to pass it by value.